Calculate streaks at scale
So I need to calculate the streaks of a user (the number of consecutive days he created an entry). For the moment, I made a query that groups entries and it gives me the last group of streaks. Here is a part of the schema (postgres) :
CREATE TABLE "diaries" (
"id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"text" VARCHAR(4000),
"created_at" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
"user_profile_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT "diaries_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id"));

And here is the query
WITH daily_entries AS (
    SELECT
        user_profile_id,
        created_at::date AS entry_date
    FROM
        diaries
    WHERE
        user_profile_id = 1
        AND created_at::date <= CURRENT_DATE
    GROUP BY
        user_profile_id, created_at::date
),
streaks AS (
    SELECT
        user_profile_id,
        entry_date,
        entry_date - INTERVAL '1 day' * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_profile_id ORDER BY entry_date) AS streak_group
    FROM
        daily_entries
),
streaks_summary AS (
    SELECT
        user_profile_id,
        MIN(entry_date) AS streak_start,
        MAX(entry_date) AS streak_end,
        COUNT(*) AS streak_length
    FROM
        streaks
    GROUP BY
        user_profile_id, streak_group
)
SELECT
    streak_length
FROM
    streaks_summary
WHERE
    streak_end = CURRENT_DATE
    AND (user_profile_id = 1);

I am looking for a way to optimise this for scaling. I was thinking about adding a field "streak" at each entry that is calculated when created so it does not need to recalculate the streaks over the entire table but I am not sure about this solution. Are there other existing ways of doing it ?

Sample data and expected results would help immensely. This looks like a gaps-and-islands problem.

Is there a particular problem with the above query? It seems to be fairly efficient.

I think you'd want a trigger on this table, plus a a tally table. Each insert/update/delete of rows on your "diaries" would either increment or restart the streak_length and update its start/end accordingly in the separate tally table holding one row for each user_profile_id with the streak data. You could also track totals, averages and other stats in that same table and maintain them by the same trigger.

@Charlieface, it is a gaps-and-islands problem, and it works like this, but I am looking for other solutions to get this result. I have not sent it to production yet, so it is just in case, after some monitoring, I see it is too heavy or costly.

@Zegarek thanks, i will try maybe with another tables for stats like that. However, I am using Prisma so I will not use triggers but I get the idea.

Sample data (as INSERT statements) and expected results please, like I said. Help us to help you.

Maybe you just want to record the most recent date where no entry was created?

You can consider the usual solution for a gaps and islands type of task.
Whether it will be better than what you have proposed is an interesting question.
Example
select  user_profile_id,min(created_at) start_from,max(created_at) end_to,count(*) cnt
  ,count(distinct created_at::date)qd
from(
  select *
    ,sum(new_streak)over(PARTITION BY user_profile_id ORDER BY created_at) grn
    ,max(created_at)over() maxDt
  from(
    select *
    ,case when  
      lag(created_at,1,created_at)OVER(PARTITION BY user_profile_id ORDER BY created_at)::date
       >= created_at::date - INTERVAL '1 day'
       then 0 
     else 1
     end new_streak
    from diaries
    where  (user_profile_id = 1)
    AND created_at::date <= CURRENT_DATE
  )t
)
group by user_profile_id,grn
having max(created_at)::date=max(maxDt)::date

Fiddle
Upd1. This query updated for case when no row with current_date in source table.
You query also don't take account this case.
Some optimisation - take last group of rows - only last rows near current date.
select user_profile_id,min(created_at) start_from,max(created_at) end_to,count(*) cnt
  ,count(distinct created_at::date)qd
from(
  select *
    ,sum(new_streak)over(PARTITION BY user_profile_id ORDER BY created_at desc) grn
  from(
    select *
    ,case when  
      lag(created_at,1,created_at)
               OVER(PARTITION BY user_profile_id ORDER BY created_at desc)::date
       <= created_at::date + INTERVAL '1 day'
       then 0 
     else 1
     end new_streak
    from diaries
    where  (user_profile_id = 1)
    AND created_at::date <= CURRENT_DATE
  )t
)
where grn=0
group by user_profile_id




user_profile_id
start_from
end_to
cnt
qd




1
2024-06-16 19:00:00
2024-06-18 21:00:00
6
3



There we form group in desc order and take first group.



id
text
created_at
user_profile_id
new_streak
grn




15
Text 1-2
2024-06-18 21:00:00
1
0
0


14
Text 1-2
2024-06-17 18:59:00
1
0
0


13
Text 1-2
2024-06-16 22:00:00
1
0
0


12
Text 1-2
2024-06-16 21:00:00
1
0
0


11
Text 1-2
2024-06-16 20:00:00
1
0
0


10
Text 1-2
2024-06-16 19:00:00
1
0
0


9
Text 1-2
2024-06-09 20:00:00
1
1
1


8
Text 1-2
2024-06-08 19:00:00
1
0
1


7
Text 1-2
2024-06-06 19:00:00
1
1
2


6
Text 1-2
2024-06-05 19:00:00
1
0
2


5
Text 1-2
2024-06-04 19:00:00
1
0
2


4
Text 1-2
2024-06-03 19:00:00
1
0
2


3
Text 1-2
2024-06-02 19:00:00
1
0
2


2
Text 1-2
2024-06-02 19:00:00
1
0
2


1
Text 1-1
2024-06-01 19:00:00
1
0
2



Update2.
You can make a recursive query. The recursion depth in this query will be equal to the number of rows in the last group (streak).
Recursively query example
with recursive 
anchor as (
  select id,text,created_at,user_profile_id
  from diaries
  where  (user_profile_id = 1)
    AND created_at::date <= CURRENT_DATE
  order by created_at desc
  limit 1
  )
,r as(
  select 0 lvl,id,text,created_at,user_profile_id
  from anchor
  
  union all
  select lvl+1,t.id,t.text,t.created_at,t.user_profile_id
  from r inner join diaries t on t.user_profile_id=r.user_profile_id
  where t.created_at<r.created_at 
    and t.created_at::date >= (r.created_at::date - interval '1 day')
)
select user_profile_id,min(created_at) start_from,max(created_at) end_to
  ,count(distinct created_at) cnt
  ,count(distinct created_at::date)qd
from r
group by user_profile_id

If there is an index (user_profile_id,created_at), searching for 1 (anchor) row will be inexpensive. Also, join in recursion will work well on this index.
Demo

Thanks for your response ! And is there a way do it "recursively" ? Like instead of dealing with all the entries, I start with the last one and get the previous one as long as it is the day before ?
